# Transistors Circuit Analysis

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

In terms of the load, what is the significance of the following circuit?

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or 90% of the circuits does nothing to the load? It is attached to a common emitter with emitter degeneration and a voltage divider for base biasing. Or did I miss some node?

Comment: So the overall circuit acts like what?

Comment: Overall circuit does nothing to the load (if the load is that resistor named as L). Just look at the output transistor: It has no connection to the rest of the circuit. Instead, it is biased via divider resistors. With emiter degeneration and those divider resistors, it forms a constant current source IMO.

Comment: This is a trace-maze riddle. Trace the connections to the base of the rightmost transistor to find the answer already given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name the transistor's base resistor that goes up to the INPUT as \$R_1\$ and the base resistor going to ground as \$R_2\$ and the emitter resistor as \$R_e\$. Then assuming the INPUT allows the BJT, in which it is the collector load, to be in the active region and also allows the emitter to be significantly above ground, the circuit will produce a current in the load of:

$$I_{LOAD}=\frac{\beta\cdot\left(V_{INPUT}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}-V_{BE}\right)}{R_1\vert\vert R_2 +\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_e}$$

As everyone can see, as well, the rest of the circuit is there to distract.